# K6 InfluxDB + Grafana Docker : How many virtual users can I run from one container?

Tags: docker, k6

I am using K6 for Load Testing.

I have cloned the K6, Grafana, InfluxDB docker-compose set up from here:

https://github.com/loadimpact/k6

Is there a maximum limit to the number of virtual users you can ramp up to from one Docker Container?

i.e. will I need to run lots of containers to reach the required number of virtual users or can it all be done from just one container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the size of the test file , the resources (memory/CPU) of the machine and the resource allocated from the machine to the docker.

From what i understand, with enough system resources, one k6 container started using the below command is enough.

```
docker-compose run k6 run
```

Comment: Thanks again Jeevananthan. That was what I thought but somebody made me wonder if I was wrong and I would need several containers.

Comment: This is correct. Running k6 across multiple nodes is unfortunately not even that easy at this point (unless you use k6 cloud, where it is done for you). https://k6.io/docs/testing-guides/running-large-tests is a great read for possible ways to fine-tune your environment to allow for larger tests.